# Orkut api integration

Tags: android, integration

How can we get extensive API support for all Orkut features on Android.
or orkut integration with android

Answer (score 1):

There's an article on [Orkut Developer Home](http://code.google.com/apis/orkut/articles/orkroid.html) on accessing orkut from an Android application.

It mainly gives an introduction to Orkroid, an Android library project based on the  [Orkut Client Library](http://code.google.com/apis/orkut/docs/orkut-os-client.html). 
This should be enough to get you started, but there are more articles more or less relevant to the point on the first link.

Answer (score -1):

You can develop an android application extending android features like sharing photos or showing multiple agendas.

You have to make use of android points of extension, mainly providers and intent listeners, and use the Orkut API (based on OpenSocial) to implement the funcionality you want to integrate.

Comment: I don't think Orkut API will help, since it is only for applications that run inside Orkut.

Comment: There is also a REST API yo be used from other systems: http://code.google.com/intl/es-GB/apis/orkut/docs/rest/developers_guide_protocol.html